# Mongoid validates_presence_of a belongs_to item

Tags: ruby, activerecord, mongoid

How do I go about validating the presence of an item defined as belongs_to? In other words:

```
class Temp
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and I wish to make sure a user was input.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many):

> The parent document of the relation should use the `has_many` macro to indicate is has *n* number of referenced children, where the document that is referenced uses `belongs_to`.
>
> ```
> class Band
>   include Mongoid::Document
>   has_many :members
> end
>
> class Member
>   include Mongoid::Document
>   field :name, type: String
>   belongs_to :band
> end
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> # The parent band document.
> { "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9") }
>
> # The child member document.
> {
>   "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f1"),
>   "band_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9")
> }
> ```

Take note of the `band_id` that represents the `belongs_to :band` relationship. So saying:

```
belongs_to :user
```

implicitly adds a `field :user_id` to your `Temp`. That means that you can simply:

```
validates_presence_of :user_id
```

to make sure that a `:user_id` has been given. If you want to ensure that the `:user_id` is valid then you could:

```
validates_presence_of :user
```

and the validation will make sure that `temp.user` (i.e. `User.find(temp.user_id)`) finds something.

Comment: That last part was exactly what I was looking for!